# Simple question: How can I set Dark Mode on Dymola 2022?

Tags: dymola, darkmode

Is it possible to set Dark Mode on Dymola 2022? Where is the option? I cannot find it.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dark mode is activated as argument to Dymola.exe.

1. Create a shortcut to Dymola.exe
2. Add the argument `/dark` to the path in the target field
3. Start Dymola via the shortcut

[image]